# A equal closure of B

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $A,B\subset X$ be subspaces of a normed space. 
I have quite a general question:
If I want to show that

$A=\bar{B}$

where $\bar{B}$ is the closure of $B$,

is it enough to show that first $B\subset A$ dense and second that $A$ is closed? 
Thank you for your help

Comment: If you mean $B$ dense in the subspace topology of $A$ then yes.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, sorry for this imprecision! Ok great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ebough to show that :
first : A is closed and B is a subset of A, so you get the closure of B is a subset of A,
second : A is contained in any closed subset (of X) containing B, so you get A is a subset of the closure of B (because the closure of B is the intersection of all closed subsets containing B).

Comment: Ok thank you Mathstuent but do you also agree with my version?

Comment: Of course. My version is a other way, it is the second one. You are welcome.